# Keycloak remove 'Review profile' button from Account already exists form

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-18

This is my First Broker Login flow in Keycloak 18:

[image]

as you may see I disabled `Review Profile` form. Now, after initial registration the user do not need to review and update the profile info(email, first/last name).

But when I try to login with a new user from a different social provider with the same email, Keycloak correctly notifies me that Account already exists and asks how do I want to proceed. And there, still there is `Review Profile` option:

[image]

and after pressing this button nothing happens.

How to remove it and only leave `Add to existing account` option there?